# error after installation when i opened that form then this error occured

Tags: vb.net, exception

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Public Class frmStatement

    Public compName As String
    Dim pfield, pfield1, pfield2 As New ParameterField
    Dim pfields As New ParameterFields
    Dim an1, an2, an3 As String
    Dim answer1 As Double


    Dim pdiscrete, pdiscrete1, pdiscrete2 As New ParameterDiscreteValue

    Private Sub frmStatement_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim rpt As New rptStatementUnpaidPart   'The report you created. sub report1
        Dim rpt1 As New rptStatementPaidPart()
        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("bookStore.My.MySettings.db_bookStoreConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim MyCommand As New SqlCommand()

        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim myDS As New dsBill  'The DataSet you created.

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New dsBillDetails
        Dim adp1 As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds1 As New dsCustomerInfo

        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()

        Try
            MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
            MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bill where status='unpaid' or status='partial paid' and companyName ='" + compName + "'"
            MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
            ' myDS.Tables().Clear()

            myDA.Fill(myDS, "Customers")

            rpt.SetDataSource(myDS.Tables(1)) 'datasource1
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        Catch Excep As InvalidCastException
            MessageBox.Show(Excep.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
               MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        myConnection.Close()

        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()

        Try

            cmd.Connection = myConnection

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bill where status='paid'or status ='Credit' and companyName ='" + compName + "'"


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd

            '   ds.Tables.Clear()

            adp.Fill(ds, "newTable")

            ' Form2.a = ds.Tables("newTable")
            rpt1.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1
        Catch ex As InvalidCastException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        myConnection.Close()
        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()

        Dim orpt As New rptStatementMain
        'total for val 1
        ' Dim daMyName As New SqlDataAdapter
        'Dim dsMyName As New DataSet
        Dim answer As Double
        Dim mySelectQuery As String = "Select SUM (total) FROM tbl_bill where status='paid' or status ='Credit' and companyName ='" + compName + "'"
        Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
        'myConnection.Open()
        ' daMyName.SelectCommand = myCmd



        answer = myCmd.ExecuteScalar()



        myConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show(answer)
        an1 = Convert.ToString(answer)

        MessageBox.Show(an1)

        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()

        Try


            'for val2

            Dim mySelQuery As String = "Select SUM (total) FROM tbl_bill where status='unpaid' or status='partial paid' and companyName ='" + compName + "'"
            Dim myCmmd As New SqlCommand(mySelQuery, myConnection)

            'myConnection.Open()

            '  daMyName.SelectCommand = myCmmd

            answer1 = myCmmd.ExecuteScalar()
            myConnection.Close()

            MessageBox.Show(answer)
            an2 = Convert.ToString(answer1)

            MessageBox.Show(an2)
        Catch ex As InvalidCastException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        'If answer1 = 1 Then
        '    answer1 = 0
        'Else
        '    answer1 = answer1
        'End If
        ' MessageBox.Show(answer1)
        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then myConnection.Open()

        Try
            'status='unpaid' or status='partial paid' and 
            MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
            MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer where companyName ='" + compName + "'"
            MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            adp1.SelectCommand = MyCommand
            adp1.Fill(ds1, "Customers")

            orpt.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables("Customers")) 'datasource1
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        Catch Excep As InvalidCastException
            MessageBox.Show(Excep.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
           MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        myConnection.Close()
        pfield.Name = "val1"
        pdiscrete.Value = an1

        pfield.CurrentValues.Add(pdiscrete)
        pfields.Add(pfield)

        pfield1.Name = "val2"
        pdiscrete1.Value = an2

        pfield1.CurrentValues.Add(pdiscrete1)
        pfields.Add(pfield1)

        Dim totalAnswer As Double

        totalAnswer = answer - answer1
        MessageBox.Show(totalAnswer)
        an3 = Convert.ToString(totalAnswer)
        MessageBox.Show(an3)
        ' MessageBox.Show(totalAnswer)
        pfield2.Name = "val3"
        pdiscrete2.Value = an3

        pfield2.CurrentValues.Add(pdiscrete2)
        pfields.Add(pfield2)
        'orpt.SetDataSource = ds1.Tables(1)
        orpt.Subreports("rptStatementUnpaidPart.rpt").SetDataSource(myDS.Tables(1))
        orpt.Subreports("rptStatementPaidPart.rpt").SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
        CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDrillDown = False
        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields


        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = orpt

    End Sub

    Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_HandleException(source As Object, e As ExceptionEventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.HandleException

    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: bookStore.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 588c3a92
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualBasic
  Problem Signature 05: 12.0.51209.34209
  Problem Signature 06: 5348c443
  Problem Signature 07: 32b
  Problem Signature 08: 21d
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidCastException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Increase the extents of your Try Catch. Include a more generic error trap too. Possibly more useful info in the error messages to show where you are in the code when the failure occurs.

Comment: I would say look into breaking your code up aswell a little into separate methods. There's a lot going on in that form load method. Break it up into chunks with error handling and you'll find that you can debug a lot easier.

Comment: it is giving error when i run it on visual studio. but after creating exe and installing it in another system it shows me System.InvalidCastException